# Add totals at the renderer column in the magento grid

Tags: magento

I want to add total at the end of Magento grid, so i use getTotals function. This function working fine for all the column. But some column has renderer, in that case i am not getting totals for renderer column, Please give any idea, how can i achieve this? For calcification, Please see the attach image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you got answer if yes please post here

Comment: Im getting the exact same issue!, did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Set a getTotals function in your Grid.php

```
public function getTotals()
{
    $totals = new Varien_Object();
    $fields = array(
        'subtotal' => 0, //actual column index, see _prepareColumns()
        'productargin' => 0
    );
    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
        foreach($fields as $field=>$value){
            $fields[$field]+=$item->getData($field);
        }
    }
    //First column in the grid
    $fields['entity_id']='Totals';
    $totals->setData($fields);
    return $totals;
}
```